# Play2's Ebean Notation to Create Models

Tags: playframework-2.0

Ebean is using a very similar JPA annotation to map objects into a database. I've been checking out `@OneToOne @OneToMany @ManyToMany @ManyToOne` relationships.

I just learned that inverse field is very inefficient (when use `@mappedBy` to determine a bidirectional relationship).

I know normally, if I don't use ORM and just use SQL to create my own database structure, when I encounter this problem:

Articles <-> Tags

This is a many to many relationship. An article can have many tags, and one tag can be attached to many articles.

Normally, with SQL, I will create a Article table and a Tag table. Then I will create a separate table with two columns:

Article_Tag Table:

```
PrimaryKey ID (int)
ArticleID (int) ForeignKey to Article Table
TagID (int) ForeignKey to Tag Table
```

Article Table:

```
PrimaryKey ArticleID (int)
Article Title (varchar)
```

Tag Table:

```
PrimaryKey TagID (int)
Tag Title (varchar)
```

My only problem now is how should/can I translate/rewrite this with Ebean(JPA) notation?

First, do I need to create a model named Article_Tag in order for this Article_Tag table or is it created by Ebean automatically?

Second, how should I annotate my article model and my tag model to describe this relationship? Which one is `@mappedBy` which one?

Third, if I use `@mappedBy`, will it generate inverse field? Should I and how do I avoid using it?

Comment: A lot of excellent questions! Honestly, I would love to know the answer to most of them too.  I've spent some time on the problem, and think that others have had some success, but I can't seem to get the incantations right.  After a couple days of trying I rage-quit and implemented the association table and helper methods manually.  I would consider tagging this with `ebean` as well as it's definitely in the ORM layer of the framework.  You may also consider searching the [ebean mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ebean) for help, and let me know if you have any success.